# How to pass an array of id's as parameters for a delete request in javascript

Tags: javascript, rest, http-delete

I have an array of id's whihc i want to append to a delete request.
How should i append the params to the url request?

var deleteArray = ['1', '5', '6'];

if i want to send a request in this format http://localhost/xxx/employees?ids=1&ids=5&ids=6   for delete

How do i parse the array contents to build the **ids=1&ids=5&ids=6** for the request url for delete?

My concern is the "&" , how could i append "& and build the string for the url request in javascript

Comment: `jquery.serialize()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var deleteArray = ['1', '5', '6'];
```

You need key=value pairs so…

```
var pairs = deleteArray.map(function (value) { return "id=" + encodeURIComponent(value) });
```

Then you need them joined by ampersands so:

```
var query_string = pairs.join("&");
```

```js
var deleteArray = ['1', '5', '6'];
var pairs = deleteArray.map(function (value) { return "id=" + encodeURIComponent(value) });
var query_string = pairs.join("&");
console.log(query_string);
```

Answer (score 2):

To pass the array in the Get you should create ids[]=1&ids[]=2 etc

Here is how you will create the GET URL

```
var url = 'http://localhost/xxx/employees?ids[]=' + deleteArray.join('&ids[]=');
```

This will create URL like

```
 http://localhost/xxx/employees?ids[]=1&ids[]=5&ids[]=6
```

Comment: The use of `[]` in query string key names is a peculiarity of PHP. Most systems don't need it.

Comment: Thanks Quentin. Good to know